# Windows 10 closing folders after awakening from stand by

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

So yesterday I programmed my pc to go into standby mode using Vista Shutdown app.
Today When I turned it on, all my folders where closed, but the programs were opened. I've searched everywhere in the web to find out what's going on, without luck.

How do I prevent Windows 10 from closing my folders or anything else after I put it into Standby?

Comment: Usually in explorer options there is a radio button for keep folders open on reboot but not from sleep mode so much for Win-doh  X

Comment: The most recent version of Vista Shutdown I found is from 2012.  Are you sure it's compatible with Win 10?

Comment: Well, it runs and works, but I'm open for new suggestions. Got any similar freeware for Windows 10?